# Stripe | Invoice address does not appear on invoice pdf

Tags: php, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I wrote a subscription system with php, everything works perfectly. Payments are received automatically. but there is only one small problem when it comes to billing. The address of the customer must be included in the invoice. I did not write the invoice anywhere in the code section. stripe automatically generates the invoice. Unfortunately, there is no address on the invoice. When I asked support, they told me that the address will not be displayed in test mode, but when we switched live mode, it still did not work. Thanks for your help in advance.

Invoice Without Address [image]

Invoice With Address And Draft Invoice [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Stripe displays the customer.address property as the address on invoices. Billing address collected via checkout for example, isn't displayed on the invoice.
You could check customer details on the dashboard and make sure that they have an address shown under details:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rylmp.png)

Comment: check to make sure you have set the `country` of the Customer address.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you reach back out to support and ask them to escalate this as I don't think their answer was correct, but there's no way for anyone to look at the details of the invoice from here.

It's possible that Customer object for the person without an address [has no address](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-address) - that's the only thing I can think of offhand.

Comment: I fill in full customer information and even shipping information. Customer is created successfully, invoice is issued, e-mail is sent successfully successful. but only the address is not shown on the invoice

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to Support then: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: @DoğuşDeniz check to make sure you have set the `country` of the Customer address.

Comment: @BrendanMoore Thank you so much. You saved my life. I missed a very small detail "country". But it was seen as optional in the documentation and I did not fill it in. :(

Comment: Thanks for this tip. It really makes _no_ sense to me, but verified that the country-code must be present in order for the billing address to be on the receipt and invoice. Unfortunately, the country is not localized so it displays in English even though the receipt is localized to Norwegian!